# Adding Tutorial link automatically to a wiki page

Tags: ros, tutorial, ros-canopen, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've created a tutorial for the ros_canopen package : http://wiki.ros.org/ros_canopen.

I made the tutorial according to this guideline : http://wiki.ros.org/WritingTutorials.
The tutorial page is located here: http://wiki.ros.org/ros_canopen/tutorials

I would like the ros_canopen page to display the Tutorial links automatically in the gray square entitled "Package Links" on the upper right, but at the moment it doesn't.
I read on ROS Answers that it can take up to 3 days, but I can't find any official information regarding that, and it has been a week since I published it.

Am I missing something to get that link displayed or should I just wait longer or refresh something by myself ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395261/adding-tutorial-link-automatically-to-a-wiki-page/) by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2022-01-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've "fixed" it for you.

In order for the *Package Link* box to show the `Tutorials` link, a sub page called `Tutorials` must exist below `ros_canopen`.

It must have the correct case (ie: PascalCase), must be called *Tutorials* (not *tutorial*) *and* it must actually exist. Simply having "Tutorials" in the path/URL is not sufficient.

Now that it exists and is correctly named, `wiki/ros_canopen` shows the link to its [Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_canopen/Tutorials) sub page. It's empty though, so no one can find the tutorial. I've left that for you to fix.

> I read on ROS Answers that it can take up to 3 days, but I can't find any official information regarding that, and it has been a week since I published it.

that "three day waiting period" is for a different documentation system. The wiki does not use that.

---

With that out of the way:

First: +100 for making tutorials. Especially for `ros_canopen`, as it's largely undocumented.

Having written that: I would recommend you reconsider "abusing" the wiki tutorial system to only link to off-site content. The main idea behind the ROS wiki is for anyone with an account to be able to edit and update it. That's how we keep things going in this community (and many other communities).

Off-site content does not typically allow that. If you stop updating that PDF, it will go stale pretty quickly, and it'll be rather difficult to update by anyone else, as they don't have access to the source.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2022-02-04**:
Hi @gvdhoorn, thank you for fixing the Tutorials page, I used the lower case "tutorials" indeed. So I also deleted my wrong "tutorials" page as it can't be reach from the wiki.

Thank you for your suggestion about rethinking the tutorials presentation, and agree that it would fit better to the ROS philosophy. I am planning to make a few self-contained tutorials and to add them on the new Tutorials page.

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2022-02-18**:
Hi @gvdhoorn, I think I saw the information to create a /tutorials page as opposed to a /Tutorials on the following page, which needs to be fixed:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheWiki#To_create_tutorial_pages_under_your_package
Do you recommend reporting that typo to the maintainer of that page or can I just fix it myself ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-02-19**:
You can probably just change that yourself.